# Bug with Shopping Cart Price rules

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, shopping-cart-price-rules

All I want to do is allow a discount if someone buys 2 of these products.

If they just buy one it is full price.

I thought this would be easy and set up a Price Rule that says:

```
 If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

 If total quantity  is  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching ANY  of these conditions:
     SKU  is one of...
```

and then I added all of the products I wanted this to work for.

The Price Rule works if I add two DIFFERENT products from this small group to the Cart and the discount applies. But if I add two of the same product (with same SKUs) this doesn't work.

Comment: Are products configurable?  if so are the child products the same or not?  May be you can use categories conditions instead of the SKU as parent and child products have different ones. Also try "equal or greater than 2"

Comment: Hi thanks. Making equal or greater than 2 seems to help and confuse the cart less when other products are also added. But I really wanted to get this working so 2 of the same would discount as a Product Rule rather than Category Rule... Anyone know why 2 products have to be different for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like expected behaviour to me, otherwise you would literally not be able to create discounts for buying X or more from within a group of SKUs. If you want it to only apply if they buy two identical SKUs, you will have to add that same condition for each SKU, e.g. `2 or more of ABC OR 2 more of DEF` and so on.